# Repeat function if variable is changed?

Tags: applescript, itunes

Having trouble figuring out this loop - I want the below function to repeat ONLY if myText changes (i.e. the album the individual is listening to changes) - I have been able to make it loop a certain number of times or repeat in the event the track changes, but I want it to repeat in the event the album changes.

```
tell application "iTunes"
repeat if myText changes
if player state is playing then
    set albumName to (get album of current track)
    set myText to text 1 thru 10 of albumName
end if
end repeat
end tell

open location "http://bandsite.com/shows/" & myText
```

When the code works without the repeat command it looks like this:

```
tell application "iTunes"
if player state is playing then
set albumName to (get album of current track)
set myText to text 1 thru 10 of albumName
end if
end tell

open location "http://bandsite.com/shows/" & myText
```

I need the whole function to repeat in the event myText changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save this as a stay open application:

```
property myList : {}

on run
    set albumA to my playCheck()
    if albumA ≠ false then
        set end of myList to albumA
    else
        quit -- Quit on the next idle.
        return 1 -- Please send the next idle as soon as possible.
    end if
end run

on idle
    set albumA to my playCheck()
    if albumA ≠ false then
        set end of myList to albumA
        if (item -1 of myList) ≠ (item -2 of myList) then
            open location "http://bandsite.com/shows/" & (text 1 thru 10 of albumA)
        end if
    end if
    return 3
end idle

on playCheck()
    tell application "iTunes"
        if player state is playing then return (get album of current track)
        return false
    end tell
end playCheck
```

Comment: Still not working. I've updated my code so the app is constantly running, now the website address has to change when the album does 
    `if application "iTunes" is not running then return
     tell application "iTunes"
 if player state is playing then
  set albumName to (get album of current track)
  set myText to text 1 thru 10 of albumName
  set tempText to myText
 end if
end tell
tempText = myText
open location "http://bandsite.com/shows/" & myText
repeat while tempText = text of myText
 if tempText is not myText then
  open location "http://bandsite.com/show" & myText
 end if
end repeat`

Comment: Have you tried saving the script I posted in my answer as a stay open application?

Comment: yes - when I save it as a stay open application it doesn't work at all. when I run it in the apple script editor it only returns the date of the album (first 10 integers) but doesn't open the website. I need it to open a website and then change the website address whenever the album changes

Comment: Can I assume you opened the application while a song was playing? If not, the script quits automatically.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "nothing happens"? Does the application launch, quit, stay in dock?  Can I also assume that after you launched it with a song playing, you then changed songs to one from a different album?

Comment: I think I may have gotten it to work. There seems to be a 4-5 second delay before the website opens but it does indeed work. Thank you very much for your help and patience!

Comment: The return value of a idle handler determines the interval in seconds before the handler is called again.

Answer (score 0):

```
temptext = mytext
do
   if temptext != myText

      tell application "iTunes"
      if player state is playing then
      set albumName to (get album of current track)
      set myText to text 1 thru 10 of albumName
      end if
      end tell

     temptext = myText

   end if

while temptext==text
```

Try this

Hope this is what you want...

Comment: None of that syntax worked at all, I tried to augment it so it would fit what I need it to do but still no luck 
[br]
`Set temptext = myText
if temptext is not myText then
 tell application "iTunes"
  if player state is playing then
   set albumName to (get album of current track)
   set myText to text 1 thru 10 of albumName
  end if
 end tell
 
 temptext = myText
 
end if
open location "http://bandsite.com/shows/" & myText
repeat while temptext = text
end repeat` I get a syntax error saying "A end of line can’t go after this identifier."

Comment: oh... i'm sorry i don't know what language is this.. I thought it's a pseudo-language.. try to follow the logic! and sorry for any inconvenience

Comment: its applescripts. I think I'm really close I just can't figure out this silly loop